# How to change a channels name using discord.py v.1.0.0a?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

i've already searched a lot about this online. There I came across the API Refrence (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel) which kind of helped me finding what command I need to use. So my conculsion would be to use this code:

```
channel = client.get_channel(475772135730708480)
@client.command()
async def emoivb(ctx):
    await discord.VoiceChannel.edit(channel, name = "test")
```

the problem is that it doesnt work with this error:

```
File "C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/discordbot.py", line 25, in emoivb
    await discord.VoiceChannel.edit(channel, name = "test")
```

So this error doesnt help me at all... but im sure I just didnt understand the API refrence correctly and didnt use the command as it is supposed to be used. Im pretty new to python coding so that is the most likely thing to have happended.
If anyone has some more python knowledge and is able to understand what I did wrong I would really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: What's the full error message?  It may be telling you that `channel` is a `TextChannel` and not a `VoiceChannel`. You should just be doing `channel.edit(name='test')` anyways, for precisely this reason. You may benefit from doing some more general Python reading, like the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

The easier way would be to specify the target channel and name in the command, something like

```
@client.command()
async def emoivb(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel, *, new_name):
    await channel.edit(name=new_name)
```

This isn't perfect though:  For names with spaces you'll have to enclose the existing channel name in quotes

```
!rename "Old Channel" New Channel
```

This is because Discord doesn't support mentioning voice channels.

Comment: thx for your answer, definetly helped me, but then im getting this error:
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: channel is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: @EmotionIce Are you providing that argument when calling the command?

Comment: im providing the argument in the way that I wrote it in my initial try:
    channel = client.get_channel(475772135730708480)
but I dont think that that serves the purpose of what you meant by providing the argument. Tbh i dont really understand what I should define for channel, other than that it is a discord.VoiceChannel

Comment: @EmotionIce I wrote the command the way I did so that you pass the old and new name to the command directly.  See the example usage in my answer.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thank you so much. I lost the whole evening looking for it without you.