# Discord.py (async) How to edit channel names?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I want it so when someone joins my server, my bot edits the name of the channel id given in the code, to the new member count. But it doesn't work. Could someone help me?

### Code

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    welchannel = bot.get_channel("517298384089120768")
    await bot.edit_channel(welchannel, f"{len(set(self.bot.get_all_members()))}")
```

Comment: please edit your question and ndent all lines of code by 4 spaces

Comment: What version of `discord.py` are you using?  Try `import discord; print(discord.__version__)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the link to the API with information about how you might edit the objects directly: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel

get a channel, assign it to a variable named "channel" and here is an answer that I found

```
@client.command()
async def emoivb(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel, *, new_name):
    await channel.edit(name=new_name)
```

Sourced From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51707897/7062209

Comment: The difference is gone over in the linked thread and the documentation that would allow you to change it is the first link. I'm pretty sure it's effectively just changing "voice" to "text".