# Renaming groupchat with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

ok im big not smart i need help, im trying to change the name of a groupchat and i have no clue what im doing, im pretty sure i need to use `discord.GroupChannel.edit(name(copy))` but i have no clue, heres my code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from math import floor
import datetime
import clipboard
import time

client = discord.Client()

t1 = datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=12, day=1, hour=21, minute=57, second=0)

async def background():
    t2 = datetime.datetime.today()

    days = (t2 - t1).days
    hours = floor(days * 24)

    if hours2 != hours:
        hours2 = hours
        copy = "1500 hour call " + str(hours2) + "/1500 " + "gio 2024"

client.loop.create_task(background())
client.run('token')
```

Comment: And what? it doesn't do the expected? It raises an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a channels name using discord.py v.1.0.0a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705898/how-to-change-a-channels-name-using-discord-py-v-1-0-0a)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I'm sorry, I'm afraid you can't edit groupchat unless you use a self-bot.

If you ask me what is self-bot, Self-bot is a bot running on User Account, this is against Discord's TOS.